# Timeout when trying to connect to github using wget

Tags: ubuntu

I'm relatively new to server management and I have a home development server running a LAMP stack on Ubuntu Server version 12.10.

I'm trying to download a git repository using Putty via the following command:

`wget https://api.github.com/repos/avalanche123/Imagine/zipball/v0.3.0`

However when doing this the server is unable to connect and times out.

What I've noticed though is if then try to `ping api.github.com` it responds as normal, and then if I try the above command again it works fine for a few minutes again until it starts to time out all over again.

The only other site I've noticed this occur on is packagist.org.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your wget command (works for me!). Maybe you should review your firewall settings.

Comment: "I'm trying to download a git repository via SSH" - no, you're not. You are trying to download via https. Wget doesn't do ssh.

Comment: @EEAA Thank you for pointing that out, this has now been corrected.

Comment: Were you trying to do this during github's maintenance the other day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging I seem to have found the problem, it looks like it's a nameserver issue as described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/81057)

Changing my server's DNS to use Google's (located in `/etc/network/interfaces`) appeared to solve the problem after a restart using `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`.